# How in x32dbg/x64dbg do i automatically follow the stack (ESP) in the 'dump window'?

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86, callstack

How in x32dbg/x64dbg do i automatically follow the stack (ESP) in the dump window? So i'm not only interested to see the stack-window-view but also the live top of the stack data-dump (hex/ascii) view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `Sync with expression` on the `Dump window` and as expression use the register `esp`. After those step the dump window will follow whatever `esp` points to.

[image]
[image]